# Contacting a user for editing feedback

Tags: support

I regularly review suggested edits. One prolific editor is constantly making the same mistakes in his edits, namely misusing "a" vs. "an" and not understanding that both the "ise" and "ize" word endings can be equally valid.

Short of re-editing or rejecting all of his suggested edits what options do I have for giving him feedback on his edits?

Comment: There is another way, that I won't disclose here because it's unconventional that you can give feedback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag them for moderator attention. That's what we're here for.

Comment: Understood will do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can also contact them via the comments of any post that they have edited, using `@`, as it works for editors as well, see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)